# When converting a ForEach loop to Linq Expression, how can you debug each iteration?

Tags: c#, linq, foreach

One of the great features of ReSharper in Visual Studio 2017 is that it will refactor my foreach loops into simple Linq expressions.

So it'll take:

```
foreach (var windForecastDataRecord in good)
{
    var dbRec = new WindDayAheadHourForecast
    {
        SyncId = currentSyncJobId,
        Site = windForecastDataRecord.SITE,
        PredictionTimeEst = string.IsNullOrEmpty(windForecastDataRecord.PREDICTIONTIME)
                            ? (DateTime?) null: DateTime.Parse(windForecastDataRecord.PREDICTIONTIME),
        TimeEst = string.IsNullOrEmpty(windForecastDataRecord.TIME)
            ? (DateTime?)null : DateTime.Parse(windForecastDataRecord.TIME),
        MegaWatts = decimal.Parse(windForecastDataRecord.MW),
        MaxiumOutput = decimal.Parse(windForecastDataRecord.MAXIMUMOUTPUT),
        Flags = windForecastDataRecord.FLAGS,
        Grp = windForecastDataRecord.GROUP,
        Region = windForecastDataRecord.REGION,
        Zone = windForecastDataRecord.ZONE
    };
    dbRecords.Add(dbRec);
}
```

and make it:

```
var dbRecords = good.Select(windForecastDataRecord => new WindDayAheadHourForecast
                    {
                        SyncId = currentSyncJobId,
                        Site = windForecastDataRecord.SITE,
                        PredictionTimeEst = string.IsNullOrEmpty(windForecastDataRecord.PREDICTIONTIME)
                            ? (DateTime?) null
                            : DateTime.Parse(windForecastDataRecord.PREDICTIONTIME),
                        TimeEst = string.IsNullOrEmpty(windForecastDataRecord.TIME)
                            ? (DateTime?) null
                            : DateTime.Parse(windForecastDataRecord.TIME),
                        MegaWatts = decimal.Parse(windForecastDataRecord.MW),
                        MaxiumOutput = decimal.Parse(windForecastDataRecord.MAXIMUMOUTPUT),
                        Flags = windForecastDataRecord.FLAGS,
                        Grp = windForecastDataRecord.GROUP,
                        Region = windForecastDataRecord.REGION,
                        Zone = windForecastDataRecord.ZONE
                    })
                    .ToList();
```

BUT, my question is, when it comes time to debug or test that statement. is there a way that I can still step through each item in the collection one by one like the foreach could?

I honestly don't know how because it's like the runtime just does the work of building the collection when it's a Linq Expression. So I guess the real question is how do you debug Linq Expressions?

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the `SyncId = currentSyncJobId,` line and give it a try.

Comment: Hrmm, it only lets me break point the WHOLE body of the NEW, is that what you mean?

Comment: In my old code I could break in each and every iteration through the items in the collection I was foreaching over. So if the 5th item had something bad, I could stop four in and then look at what the 5th came through as.

Comment: I did try it, yes. I have a date parse bug, let me fix that and see if I get what I want.

Comment: Yes! That does what I want!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157570/discussion-between-paul-duer-and-mjwills).

Comment: Press F11, and put your mouse over the part of the new you want to evaluate.

Comment: Most simple thing to do here is to scope your 'new' statement put it inside a { return new }. Once you have done that, you can put a break point on the return line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't with `ForEach` - you can put a breakpoint in the middle, even in a single line statement. Just click there and press F9. `ForEach` changes nothing.

[image]

The problem is that you're trying to debug in the middle of the object initializer syntactic sugar. This is not possible. Object initializers shouldn't be this complex.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5528738/7866667

Comment: Give the original code _also_ used an object initializer (and he/she was able to breakpoint there), I am not convinced this is what the original poster needs.

Comment: "the real question is how do you debug Linq Expressions?" - this is what the poster needs, and this is what I answered in the first part of the answer - you debug them the same as anything else. I assumed the reason for the confusion was an object initializer, and I elaborated on it. Basically he/she wasn't able to breakpoint there in the original code either, because VS doesn't allow that.

Comment: Yeah I like what j4nw is saying and the link he provided. I do plan to simplify my object initializer.